# How to make name a row name in R dataframe without modifications

Tags: r, dataframe, r-rownames

I am making one of the column names to be a row name in data frame in R. However, whenever I am making the same, X is adding up before the numbers, hyphens (-) are replaced by dots (.) Is there a way to handle this in R, to keep the name as it is without any change. These type of changes are creating issues while merging two dataframes. Please assist me with this.

Here is the example of the code and dataframe:

**Before**

```
dput(tail(Probe.annotation.table, 10))
structure(list(ID = c("100306034_TGI_at", "100311622_TGI_at", 
"merck2-rsta-239398_at", "merck2-NM_000839-381.A_at", "merck2-NM_004103-360.B_at", 
"merck2-HCV_at", "merck2-HCV_revcomp_at", "merck2-HIV_at", "merck2-HIV_revcomp_at", 
"merck2-flu_at"), EntrezGeneID = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), GeneSymbol = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), GB_ACC = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), miRNA_ID = c("", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", ""), ORF = c("", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", ""), PROBE_DERIVED_FROM_TRANSCRIPT = c("", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", ""), SPOT_ID = c("RosettaGeneID:BX647964", 
"RosettaGeneID:AK124699", "RosettaGeneID:rsta-239398", "RosettaGeneID:NM_000839-381.A", 
"RosettaGeneID:NM_004103-360.B", "RosettaGeneID:HCV", "RosettaGeneID:HCV_revcomp", 
"RosettaGeneID:HIV", "RosettaGeneID:HIV_revcomp", "RosettaGeneID:flu"
), RosettaGeneModelID = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"")), row.names = 52369:52378, class = "data.frame")
```

**Code**

```
rownames(Probe.annotation.table) <- make.names(Probe.annotation.table$ID, unique=TRUE)
```

**After**

```
put(tail(Probe.annotation.table, 10))
structure(list(ID = c("100306034_TGI_at", "100311622_TGI_at", 
"merck2-rsta-239398_at", "merck2-NM_000839-381.A_at", "merck2-NM_004103-360.B_at", 
"merck2-HCV_at", "merck2-HCV_revcomp_at", "merck2-HIV_at", "merck2-HIV_revcomp_at", 
"merck2-flu_at"), EntrezGeneID = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), GeneSymbol = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), GB_ACC = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), miRNA_ID = c("", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", ""), ORF = c("", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", ""), PROBE_DERIVED_FROM_TRANSCRIPT = c("", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", ""), SPOT_ID = c("RosettaGeneID:BX647964", 
"RosettaGeneID:AK124699", "RosettaGeneID:rsta-239398", "RosettaGeneID:NM_000839-381.A", 
"RosettaGeneID:NM_004103-360.B", "RosettaGeneID:HCV", "RosettaGeneID:HCV_revcomp", 
"RosettaGeneID:HIV", "RosettaGeneID:HIV_revcomp", "RosettaGeneID:flu"
), RosettaGeneModelID = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"")), row.names = c("X100306034_TGI_at", "X100311622_TGI_at", 
"merck2.rsta.239398_at", "merck2.NM_000839.381.A_at", "merck2.NM_004103.360.B_at", 
"merck2.HCV_at", "merck2.HCV_revcomp_at", "merck2.HIV_at", "merck2.HIV_revcomp_at", 
"merck2.flu_at"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
newdata <- Probe.annotation.table %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "ID")
```

Comment: thank you very much for the response. I could get desired output. What does unique=TRUE indicate?

Comment: forces resultant names to be unique. `make.names(c("a and b", "a-and-b"), unique = TRUE)` results in "a.and.b" and "a.and.b.1"

Comment: thank you. So, the solution provided by you should be sufficient.